# Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting python-socketio

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have this code, whenever the user goes to this certain endpoint, it is supposed to emit a message to a python client, which then gets some data and then returns it back as a callback so I can show the users the data.

This is the server-side code (NodeJS):

```
app.get('/hueapi/lights', verifyToken, (req,res) => {
  const bridgeIDFromApp = req.header('bridgeID');
  const socketID = socketRefDic[bridgeIDFromApp]['socketID'];
  io.to(socketID).emit('getAllLights', 'getAllLights', function(data){
      res.send(data); // The callback function that shows the data given by the python client
  });
});
```

It just sends a simple 'getAllLights' message to the python client in question and then runs the function which provides the data.

This is the client-side code (python):

```
def getAllLights(data):
    lightData = requests.get('http://localhost:4000/lights/')
    return lightData
```

Am I doing the call back wrong or? I just want to send the data straight back to the user after retrieving it.

EDIT:

I am now using `io.to(...).emit(...)` instead of `io.send(...).emit(...)` yet I am still getting the error saying I'm broadcasting, yet I'm not, am I?

Comment: Callbacks or "acknowledgement" is not support for broadcasts

Comment: @Marc I'm not doing a broadcast though, I'm sending something to a specific socket aren't I?

Comment: In the titel you say "broadcasting at namespace" and you invoke `io.send(...)` so its a broadcast ;) EDIT: where is the `io.send` method documented ?!

Comment: @Marc how would I achieve the same thing by using a callback to specific sockets/clients then? Is it even possible, I’m even finding it hard trying to find the correct syntax for sending specific sockets data, there’s tonnes of answers saying different things out there.

Comment: There is now method for ack callbacks in broadcasts. you could implement that by your own if you need it.

Comment: @Marc I'm using `io.to(...).emit(....)` and it still says I'm broadcasting, I'm sending a message to one client only, so I'm not sure how I'm broadcasting? Could you provide a link on the method for ack callbacks, even though I'm sure I'm not broadcasting?

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-send-%E2%80%A6args-ack You have to call `emit` on a sinlge `socket` object

Comment: @Marc is there any way of getting the socket object with the socket ID then?

Comment: Store the socket object & socket id in a object. socket id = key, socket object = value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the ack method will work for you unless it is implemented on the python side as well. The reason that you are still getting the broadcasting error is because `io.to` does not return a socket it returns a room which does broadcast.

Probably easier to just have a separate endpoint on the client side. Which your python code doesn't even attempt from what I see. The python code should still be able to write to the socket.

So to implement your own ack function you would simply write your ack message to the socket. If you need it to be statefully namespaced then you would have to include an address for the python code to reference with your `getAllLights` message.

Node:

```
app.get('/hueapi/lights', verifyToken, (req,res) => {
  const bridgeIDFromApp = req.header('bridgeID');
  const socketID = socketRefDic[bridgeIDFromApp]['socketID'];
  const uniqAck = "some unique endpoint path";
  
  const socket = getSocketByID(socketID);
  socket.on(uniqAck, (data) => res.send);
  socket.emit('getAllLights', 'getAllLights:'+uniqAck);
});
```

Python:

```
def getAllLights(data):
    lightData = requests.get('http://localhost:4000/lights/');
    return (lightData, split(data, ":")[1]); // split if its not already done by this point.

// capture 'value' from getAllLights when it is called...
socket.emit(value[1], value[0]);
```